Identifying maximum and minimum in Lagrange multiplier problems via compactness of constraint
I am currently studying constrained optimization with Lagrange multipliers, and I am confused about an argument that is used in several examples. Say $f$ is the function we are trying to optimize under the constraint $\mathbf g (\mathbf x)=\mathbf 0$. Let $S$ be the solution set of $\mathbf g (\mathbf x)=\mathbf 0$. We apply Lagrange's method and find, say, two critical points of $f$ restricted to $S$, and now it is upon us to identify whether these critical points are maxima or minima or neither. A common argument is to argue somehow that $S$ is compact, and since $f$ is continuous, then $f|_S(S)$ is compact, so $f$ must attain a maximum and a minimum. These must then be our critical points, so we choose the larger corresponding $f$ value to be the maximum and the other to be the minimum.
I am quite  confused. I remember in single-variable calculus, to find extrema, we first found the critical points, and tested them to see if they were local extrema. We then had to additionally check the boundary points of the interval we were considering—sometimes, the global extrema were not local extrema (i.e., did not have derivative $0$). For example, if we tried to find the extrema of $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-1,1]$, we would find there is one critical point that does not correspond to anything, and that the global extrema occur at the boundaries, where the derivative is not $0$.
What's different about the case with Lagrange multipliers? The solution set being compact and $f$ being continuous means that there is a constrained maximum and minimum, yes, but what is the justification for them corresponding to critical points?
For example, my book employs this argument in a problem where the constraints are
$$
x^2+\frac{y^2}{2}=1 \\
x+z=1
$$
It produces two critical points from the Lagrange multiplier method and then argues that the solution set is compact, and so $f$ will have a maximum and minimum on this set. These must be critical points, it claims, and we have only found two, so these must be it.

While I do not know what book you are using, I believe their argument is using compactness of $S$ and continuity of $f(x)$ only to ensure that both a maximizer and a minimizer of $f(x)$ over all $x\in S$ exists.  That is all.
You are correct that such maximizers and minimizers can only exist at critical points of the function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which are points where the derivative is zero, points where the derivative does not exist, and points on the boundary of $S$. However, this fact is not needed here and I doubt they are using it. The Lagrange multipier method says we do not care about finding critical points of $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, rather we care about finding critical points of a related Lagrangian.
So your book is likely using a necessary condition of Lagrange multipliers: If the problem of minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=0$ has a minimizer point $x^* \in S$ (which it does by the compactness of $S$ and continuity of $f$) then under mild regularity conditions, there must be a vector $\lambda$ such that
$$\nabla f(x^*) + \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\nabla g_i(x^*)=0$$
This is not a sufficient condition: You might find a $\lambda$ for which $\nabla f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\nabla g_i(x)=0$ has solutions that intersect the set $S$, but these are not minimizers or maximizers (see example below).

Example: Define real-valued functions $f,g$ by
\begin{align}
f(x) &= x^3 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
g(x) &= x(x-1)(x-2)\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
We consider the problem of either maximizing or minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=0$. Define
$S= \{x \in\mathbb{R}: g(x)=0\}$.
Then

$S=\{0,1,2\}$ is a compact set.
The maximizer of $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=0$ is $x^*=2$.
The minimizer of $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=0$ is $x^*=0$.
$1 \in S$ but $1$ is neither a maximizer nor a minimizer.

It may also help to observe that $g'(0)\neq 0$, $g'(1)\neq 0$, $g'(2)\neq 0$.
For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we can look for solutions $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to
$$f'(x) + \lambda g'(x)=0$$
that are also in the set $S$. This is equivalent to finding points in $S$ that are also solutions to:
$$ 3x^2 + \lambda(3x^2-6x+2)=0$$
Most values of $\lambda$ do not produce solutions to $f'(x)+\lambda g'(x)=0$ that are also in $S$, but $\lambda=3$ does. Indeed, suppose we take $\lambda=3$. We find solutions are $x \in \{1/2, 1\}$ and   indeed $\{1/2,1\}\cap S = \{1\}$.   But $x=1$ is neither a minimizer nor a maximizer for the original constrained problem. This does not contradict the existence theorem because, while $\lambda=3$ does not work, $\lambda=0$ works for the minimizer $x^*=0$, indeed, $x^*=0$ solves $f'(x)+0g'(x)=0$. There is also a $\lambda$ that works for the maximizer $x^*=2$, can you find it?

Thank you. For a concrete example, see Example 9 on page 7 of https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mark.coleman/MATH20132/Present/Notes%202021-22/Section%205%20Extremal%20Values%202021-22.pdf. Or for something far more terse, Example 3 of these notes: https://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/teaching/2016-17/269-vector-analysis/pdfs/lagrange.pdf (I've seen many examples like this that just assume that to find extrema we look for critical points like it's the most obvious thing.)

Your first Example 9 indeed only uses compactness of $S$ and continuity of $f$ to ensure a minimizer and a maximizer exists for $f$ over $x \in S$. They implicitly assume $f$ is nonconstant over $S$ so that the minimizer is  different from the maximizer.  They do not care about critical points of $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. An existence theorem for Lagrange multipliers holds. They found only two possible points that can work for this theorem. Since at least one point works for a minimizer, and at least one for a maximizer, it must be these two. If we found 3, then 1 of them may be useless.

For Example 9, they do care about the critical points, don't they? The top of page 8 says "We have, therefore, two critical points of $f$ restricted to the surface...". In general, my understanding is that the Lagrange multiplier method says that if $x$ is a local extremum of $f\rvert_S$, then it must be a critical point of the Lagrangian, i.e., the critical points of the Lagrangian gives us candidates for local extrema for $f\rvert_S$. Yet I do not see how the fact that $f\rvert_S$ has global extrema helps us identify what the critical points of the Lagrangian correspond to,

since global extrema do not need to be local extrema (as seen in the single-variable case).

Every global extremum is also a local extremum. For the top of page 8 it should say "We have, therefore, only two critical points of $\mathcal{L}$ that are in $S$..."

Ah, yes. What I meant is the global extremum need not have derivative $0$. If I recall correctly, if $x$ is an interior point of the domain and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $Df(x) = 0$ if $x$ is a local extremum. This does not apply to boundary points. So say we established there is a global max and min for $f\rvert_S(S)$. The global max and min could be boundary points on $S$, and so it need not be a critical point of the Lagrangian, since the proof of the Lagrange multiplier theorem (e.g. second link from CMU) relies on the fact that $Df\vert_S(x)=0$,

which only follows from $x$ being a local extremum of $f\vert_S$ if $x$ is an interior point.

Indeed the global max $x^$ of $f$ over $x \in S$ can be on boundary of $S$ and does not need to have $\nabla f(x^)=0$. Under regularity, there is a $\lambda$ for which $x^*$ is a zero-derivative point of the Lagrangian. The proof does not rely on $f$ restricted to $S$ being a zero derivative point (I do not know what that would mean). It uses an implicit function for which the zero derivative condition holds. Also, the proof given there is incomplete as we cannot use the implicit function theorem if $n=d$ which is what happens in my example above. (But the theorem holds easily when $n=d$).

I see. At my level (advanced calculus, introductory real analysis), all the resources only state the theorem for the case where $d>n$. Perhaps a proper course in optimization would introduce the full version of the Lagrange multiplier theorem. I think this discussion has helped me get a better understanding of the topic. Thank you for your patience!

There are a few reasons why we typically don't check for local constrained extrema in these types of problems. The first is that the actual conditions for classifying local extrema are much more technical. See for example this note set. Determining whether a stationary point of the Lagrangian is a local maximum or minimum in $\mathbb{R}^n$ requires constructing the $n+1\times n+1$ bordered Hessian matrix and determining whether it is negative/positive definite on a specific subspace determined from the derivatives of the constraint. That's not particularly easy!
The other reason is that a point being a local max/min generally tells us very little about the global min/max. Take for example the problem
$$
\min~x+y \\ \mathrm{s.t.}~xy=1.
$$
The stationary points are $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. If you use the bordered Hessian or paramterize the constraint curve and substitute into the objective, you will find that $(1,1)$ is a local minimum and $(-1,-1)$ is a local maximum, even though $f(1,1) >f(-1,-1)$! Furthermore, neither of these are global extrema for this problem since the constraint set is unbounded and the objective function can take on arbitrarily small or large values. For these reasons, we typically stick to compact constraint sets or objectives that have simple behavior far from the origin if the constraint set is unbounded so that finding global extrema is easier when teaching a multivariable calculus class.
